# Oracle Why Exists Query Returns This Result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am confusing using exists to compare two data between two tables. I am expecting to get 0 rows from query but it returns some data. I don't know why.

```
select main_rule, child_rule from scoredef_detail s where s.main_rule = 515;
1   515 516
2   515 517

select main_rule, child_rule from scoredef_detail_at s where s.main_rule = 515;
1   515 516
2   515 517
```

This query returns all of them above. I am trying to get differences. These columns are foreign keys of some other tables. Can it related with other table's records?

```
select main_rule, child_rule
  from scoredef_detail s
 where exists
 (select main_rule, child_rule
          from scoredef_detail_at sa
         where s.main_rule = sa.main_rule and (s.child_rule <> sa.child_rule));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What differences?  What results do you want?

Comment: Both of these data on both table are equal. I am expecting not to see any data from exists query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `full join` to get mismatches:

```
select s.*, sa.*
from (select main_rule, child_rule
      from scoredef_detail s
      where s.main_rule = 515
     ) s full join
     (select main_rule, child_rule
      from scoredef_detail_at s
      where s.main_rule = 515
     ) sa
     on sa.main_rule = s.main_rule and sa.child_rule = s.child_rule
where sa.main_rule is null or s.main_rule is null;
```

This will show the pairs that are in one table but not the other.

Comment: yes this query works but i don't know why my query didn't work as I expected

Answer (score 1):

For parent row "1", child row "2" satisfies the EXISTS clause.  For parent row "2", child row "1" satisfies the EXISTS clause.  So both rows are returned.

Comment: Thanks it made sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in Oracle is to use the `MINUS` keyword and create two different queries, `A MINUS B` and `B MINUS A`, like this:

```
with
q1 as (
  -- could be an arbitrarily complex query
  select main_rule, child_rule from scoredef_detail
),
q2 as(
  -- another arbitrarily complex query...columns must match q1
  select main_rule, child_rule from scoredef_detail_at
)
-- Can leave this part untouched
select 'in Q1 but not Q2' as description, q1.* from q1
  minus
select 'in Q1 but not Q2' as description, q2.* from q2
union
select 'in Q2 but not Q1' as description, q2.* from q2
  minus
select 'in Q2 but not Q1' as description, q1.* from q1
/
```

This kind of query is quite useful when writing ETL test scripts that compare source tables with target tables but the transformations are a bit cumbersome for the full join technique. It's another tool for your kit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your original query fails and thus returns data is that you have 2 qualifying rows (515, 516) and (515, 517) each of which exist in both tables.  When positioned on either one your criteria "s.main_rule = sa.main_rule and (s.child_rule <> sa.child_rule))" returns the other one. When positioned on s(515, 516) and evaluating sa(515, 517) that expression becomes "515=515 and 516 <> 517" which evaluates True and so the EXISTS predicate evaluates true thus the row is output. The same scenario. occurs when evaluating (515, 517).  
@GordonLinoff query returns what you desire because as he says it "show the pairs that are in one table but not the other"